# Playa - get all entries where playa is empty

Tags: playa

I have articles related to products (set up with Playa), and then some articles are not related to any product.

Is there a way to get all the articles where the Playa-field is empty?

Comment: Have you tried a custom query to get the entry ids that have no related entries in exp_playa_relationships?

Comment: @AndrisSevcenko No, I'm not that good with custom queries. Could you maybe help me get started with a custom query that would get those entries?

Comment: When you say "get", how do you mean? For use in your templates? Or a list in the control panel? Or just a one-time list of IDs/titles so you can perform some operation on those entries?

Comment: I have a separate page on my site where I want to list all the articles not related to any product. So I guess a list of entry-ids would be fine, because I can plug those directly into `{exp:channel:entries}`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need some help with a query, I wrote this. You will need to change the part where channel = 4, and enable php on input for this template. I think this might work for you.

EDIT: You can just use the not in the entry id parameter

```
<?php

    // First we get the entries that are a playa parent
    $dontIncludeArray = array();

    $dontIncludeQuery = ee()->db->select('parent_entry_id')
                        ->from('playa_relationships')
                        ->get();

    foreach ( $dontIncludeQuery->result_array() as $row )
    {

        $dontIncludeArray[] = $row['parent_entry_id'];  

    }

    $dontInclude = implode('|' , $dontIncludeArray);
    ?>
 {exp:channel:entries channel="foo" entry_id="not <?php echo $dontInclude; ?>"}
        {title}<br>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks! It looks like it's really close, but it's getting all the articles. I've tried to set the `where_not_in` to take the `$dontIncludeArray` as the second parameter, as someone suggested that it should take an array and not a string, but that didn't help either. I've also tried echoing out `$dontInclude`, and it does contains an entry_id which shouldn't be outputted, so that query works fine.

Comment: I have edited my post, but you have enabled php on input right? This will not work on output

Comment: PS! "You may award your bounty in 19 hours.", so you'll have to wait for the bounty (: